# Suggestion for removing notification on flags

Tags: feature-request, flagging, notifications

On the Main site I have the little yellow square with a 5 inside indicating that there are 5 flags that needs attention. I have already "voted" on each of these flags, but every time I come to the site I click the little yellow square. I want to suggest that the notification on the front show the number of flags that I have not already "voted" on.